# Have I encountered a limit to mpmath's floating-point precision?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, mpmath

[`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/) purports to support "arbitrary-precision floating-point arithmetic."

And yet . . .

```
>>> import mpmath
>>> 1 + mpmath.erf(-5.921)
mpf('1.1102230246251565e-16')
>>> 1 + mpmath.erf(-5.922)  # I expect a smaller positive number here.
mpf('0.0')
```

Am I missing something?  Or is this a fundamental limitation of `mpmath`?

@jonrsharpe has suggested that the problem is that I've submitted a `float` to `erf`.  However, the code below shows that this is not the problem:

```
>>> 1 + mpmath.erf(mpmath.mpf('-5.922'))
mpf('0.0')
```

Comment: `mpmath`'s arithmetic may be arbitrarily-precise, but *you're passing it a `float`, which isn't*.

Comment: *"there's no way to represent any number of interest in `mpmath` without it being a `float`"* - yes there is, see http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1229/trunk/doc/build/basics.html?highlight=float#number-types and try `mpf('-5.922')`. You may also need to adjust the precision.

Comment: No, I don't see much point doing a round trip via `str` - the point is that once you start using `float`, it's difficult to guarantee getting back to arbitrary precision. You should use `mpf` objects from as early in the process as you can.

Comment: And have you tried adjusting `prec`/`dps`? Arbitrary precision doesn't mean infinite precision, and even the example on the homepage includes `mp.dps = 50`!

Comment: The `mpmath` documentation explicitly states you should use strings and not not floats to initialize an `mpf`. http://mpmath.org/doc/0.19/basics.html#providing-correct-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this particular case has to do with `mpmath`'s [global `prec`ision setting](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/basics.html#setting-the-precision) being too low. The default value for `prec` is

```
>>> mpmath.mp.prec
53
```

When I set it to `100`, I get the result I was expecting:

```
>>> 1 + mpmath.erf(-5.922)
mpf('5.5236667058718205581661131647751e-17')
```

In this case the speed difference isn't noticeable, but note that increasing the precision generally increases the time required to compute the result.

Comment: Note that @jonrsharpe's point about floats vs. strings still holds.  Compare `1 + mpmath.erf(mpmath.mpf(0.001))` with `1 + mpmath.erf(mpmath.mpf("0.001"))` after setting `mpmath.mp.dps = 100`.

Comment: You are also seeing the effects of cancellation. Because `1` and `erf(-5.922)` are very close in absolute magnitude, you lose more than 50 bits of precision when you do the addition. The correct result to 100 bits of precision is `5.5236667058717915711865772335092e-17`. Your result is only correct for the first 13 digits or so.

Comment: @casevh Right. The better thing to do is use `mpmath.erfc(-x)`.